# Nginx as a reverse proxy for Apache, Php prompted for download instead of executed

Tags: nginx, httpd

I am trying to make Nginx as a reverse Proxy for Apache on a centos 7 server.

Here is what I did until now:

Create a config file for Nginx: *nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf*

```
server {
    listen   80; 

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/; 
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name _; 

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

     }

     location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Change 2 lines in */etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf*:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
DocumentRoot "/usr/share/nginx/html/"
```

I created a file named info.php in /usr/share/nginx/html, and put `<?php infophp();?>` in it, but when I try to load the page http://My_Ip/info.php I get a pop up to download the file, whereas I want the file to be executed.

I passed this command *httpd -M | grep* php to see if the Php module is present in my apache web server, and I get "php7_module (shared)", so I guess it is.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Henry

p.s: when I go on http://My_IP I get the default Nginx home page
p.s2: fot those who ask, I already posted about a related problem on serverfault (error 403), but it appears that I don't have the problem anymore (i.e if I go to see http://My_IP/any_css_file.css for instance, it well displayed, no error)

Comment: If you save the file, is it empty or does it have content? If it has content, is it the PHP script or its output?

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for your help, if I save the file it has the same content that I put when I created it i.e <?php infophp();?>, yes it's a php file/script (not its output)

Comment: OK, so your problem is in your Apache configuration, not in nginx. Why are you even using Apache anyway?

Comment: I am using Apache to process php files, because Nginx cannot do it. I mentionned in my post what I modified on my Apache conf.

Comment: You don't need Apache to process PHP files. The normal setup is nginx + php-fpm. No Apache anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelHampton but is not Apache faster than php-fpm to process php files ?

Comment: How could it possibly be faster? It's a bunch of extra overhead compared to running php directly.

Comment: Ok, so I might not need to solve my problem, I will close this post, thanks

Comment: Dont close it, the problem is your Nginx conf. Im writing an answer

Comment: @miknik ok, I don't close it :), thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an instance of PHP FPM running on your server to execute the php scripts. You can check by running

```
find / -type d -iname *fpm*
```

If this returns some results then it's already installed. Now to find out the port/socket it's listening on you can run:

```
find / -type d -iname *fpm* | xargs grep -r "^listen[= ]"
```

Which should return something like this:

```
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
```

In your Nginx config directory (usually `/etc/nginx/`) you may already have a file `fastcgi_params`, if not then create one and copy the example [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/)

Then change your php location block to include your config file and pass the request to php fpm using the port/socket returned from the command before, like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Now restart Nginx and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, the command **find / ... ^listent[= ]** gives **127.0.0.1:9000** instead of unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock, the file *fastcgi_param* was already present in */etc/nginx*, I followed instructions from [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) and I still have the same problem